# PyPDF2 output incorrect: missing words. Coding issue?

Tags: python, pdf, encoding, pypdf

I try to extract text from some .pdf files using PyPDF:

```
pdfFileObject = open(filepath, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
        count = pdfReader.numPages
        text = ''
        for i in range(count):
            page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            text += page.extractText()
```

Sometimes `text` returns (nearly) correct string (with some coding issues, like in some German texts everything is ok except of Umlauts (äöü)), but mostly (irrespective of language) it looks just like this:

```
'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nÈ\n\n'
```

I have not recognize any pattern in the selection of (almost) correctly and completely incorrectly parsed files. Some of them have tables (these are the worst, that's truth), but some of them look plain and simple.

Regrettably, PyPDF2 seems to be the only working module for me... Does this something to do with encoding? I'd like all characters be represented correctly anyway, although it's not really important in this case.

I'll be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: PyPDF2 only allows utf-8. I was not able to use PyPDF2 for cp932 (Japanese). Instead, pdfminer.six worked well.

Comment: @shimo Thank you! I managed to install proper version of pdfminer.six, and it definitely works better... Now the number of parsed words is somewhere +-20% if their actual number, not +-100% as in case of PyPDF2 =) And only one line of code instead of six.